# What is the importance of class files in Sonar analyzer?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

Since sonar is a static coda analyzer, when we need to specify binaries. It is not going to compile and build .class by itself.

What if I ran a latest source with an old binary??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you're using the Maven plugin, Sonar will not understand how to compile your code, so it's up to you to ensure that sonar is run against fresh binaries.

It's Findbugs that requires access to the compiled class files and dependency jars, in order to complete it's analysis.

Comment: There is also for instance the package cycle detection mechanism which is based on bytecode.